# about node.js / javascript sharing variable between file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some files that need database access so I have a file like this:

```
...
var dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.getDatabase= function(){
    return dynamo;
};
...
```

I wonder if different .js files use it like this:

```
var DataUtil = require('./shared/dataUtils.js');
...
var database = DataUtil.getDatabase();
....
```

are they using the same instance of the object? or just instantiating a copy for each of the .js file using the requiring?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the same instance. When you require a module, it's only loaded when it's not already loaded. So there's only one instance of a module in a node program.

From [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching):

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means
> (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
> exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
> file.

In your case, you'll have only one instance of `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`.